# Infragistics 12.1 HierarchyGrid conversion to infragistics 15.2

Tags: infragistics, ignite-ui, iggrid

I am facing below migrating issue please check it

1) Microsoft JScript runtime error: igGridUpdating was not recognized. Verify that such a feature exists and the spelling is correct. (Infragistics.ui.grid.framework.js)

2) Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method '_super'

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you reference all required dependencies for the updating feature as mentioned here - http://help.infragistics.com/jQuery/2015.2/ui.iggridupdating_hg

Dependencies

- jquery-1.9.1.js
- jquery.ui-1.9.0.js
- modernizr.js (optional)
- infragistics.ui.grid.framework.js
- infragistics.ui.grid.shared.js
- infragistics.ui.editors.js
- infragistics.ui.validator.js
- infragistics.ui.combo.js
- infragistics.ui.rating.js
- infragistics.ui.shared.js
- infragistics.datasource.js
- infragistics.util.js

The second error is caused by using an older jquery references. Please update jquery to 1.9.1 and jquery.ui to 1.9.0.